# How to get the data csv or raw numbers from cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am monitoring `Network In Average` and `Network Out Average` by cloud watch.

I can check the graph on the web.

However I want to get the csv or raw numbers data.

I have checkws around but not found the some download way or showing raw numbers.

[image]

I am familiar with php/python or crawling, but not familiar with `aws`.

Where should I start ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no build in functionality for that in console. Thus, the get the raw data, you have to use [get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data) or [get_metric_statistics](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_statistics) methods in Python using `boto3` (AWS SDK for Python).

Which one and how to use it is explained in a recent AWS blog post;

- [Should I use GetMetricData or GetMetricStatistics for CloudWatch metrics?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-getmetricdata-api/)

> It's a **best practice to use the GetMetricData** API instead of GetMetricStatistics, because you can retrieve data faster at scale with GetMetricData.

Instead of writing your own program for that, you can have a look at already developed tools for that. For example:

- [cloudwatch_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter)

Comment: Thank you very much I understood the basic idea. I will try some way you mentioned.